# Trigger - Update another object without changing any values?

Tags: trigger, formula

Is there a way to update an object without changing any of the values on its fields?

Here's the situation:

ObjectA

- dateA (date)

ObjectB

- lookup relationship with ObjectA
- formulaDateA formula(date) --> just displaying the date of dateA
- fieldB

ObjectB has a trigger in which, whenever any of its fields are updated, a trigger is fired.

However, for formulaDateA, since it is just a formula field, if dateA is change, the trigger in ObjectB will not fire.

Thus I have no choice but to create another trigger in ObjectA which will update a dummy field in ObjectB called fieldB and so, in effect, will fire off the trigger in ObjectB.

As much as possible, I don't want to create a new field called fieldB just so I can fire the trigger in ObjectB.

QUESTION:
Is their a way that I could fire the trigger of ObjectB without updating any of its' fields?

Thanks.

Comment: `update ObjectName(ID=existingId);` will trigger `ObjectName` update event;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Process Builder - it does allow to update child/related records triggered by a field change.